# Excel VBA getting an image from url

Tags: vba, excel

I'm making a macro on Excel 2013 to get the URL from a column (Column "f") and put it on the next column (Column "G") I already make a code but it doesn't work as I want

```
Sub GetShapeFromWeb(strShpUrl As String, rngTarget As Range)
    With rngTarget.Parent
       .Pictures.Insert strShpUrl
       .Shapes(.Shapes.Count).Left = rngTarget.Left
       .Shapes(.Shapes.Count).Top = rngTarget.Top
    End With
 End Sub

Sub Obtener_imagen()
On Error Resume Next
For i = 2 To 3
    Call GetShapeFromWeb(Range("f" & i).Value, Hoja1.Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Offset(6, i))
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: What does it do instead of working?  You need to be a bit more specific.

Comment: sorry , it puts the image on the column C in the first empy row , and show an error but i think the error is because the image of the url so it should be corrected if i put another URL

Comment: If you have code that isn't working - you should probably take out any `On Error Resume Next` statements and actually debug it.

Comment: Hi! Don't forget to award most helpful answer with check mark (if any of them helped you significantly to solve your problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is what you are trying to achieve

```
Sub Obtener_imagen()
 Dim fila as Integer,ultima_fila as Integer
 ultima_fila =Hoja1.Range("F65536").End(xlUp).row
 For fila =1  To ultima_fila
    With Range("G" & fila).Parent
       .Pictures.Insert Range("F" & fila)
       .Shapes(.Shapes.Count).Left = ("G" & fila).Left
       .Shapes(.Shapes.Count).Top = ("G" & fila).Top
    End With
 Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're putting this in the Range `Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Offset(6, i)`

So you're offsetting by `i` from column A. Change that `i` to a `7` to specify column G, or another variable if you need it dynamic.

Your range statement is doing the following:

1. Go To Cell A65536
2. Press Ctrl + Up to find the last used row in column A.
3. Go down 6 rows (`.Offset(6`)
4. Go right i columns (either 2 or 3, which means either column B or C)
5. Insert the image there.

This will cause you problems if column A doesn't have the same number of rows populated as column G, and it also sounds like you don't want to offset by 6 rows either.

Comment: it works but still put it on the bottom of the sheet i want it on the top like G2,G3,etc.